# package for drawing polyhedrons in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw some polyhedrons and their truncated versions in TikZ (while PSTRICKS has but I prefer PDFLaTeX). Below is the codes that I modified from the website for the case of a octahedron. For truncated cubes, icosahedrons, truncated icosahedron, dodecagon and truncated dodecagon will be more challenging. Could you help to draw such polyhedrons in the following fashion (with lines, and dashed, no shading)?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.3]%
\coordinate (C1) at (0.3,-0.15);
\coordinate (C2) at (0.55,-0.15);
\coordinate (C3) at (0.425,-0.025);
\coordinate (C4) at (0.425,-0.275); 
\coordinate (D1) at (0.85,-0.05); 
\coordinate (D2) at (0.9,0.05); 
\coordinate (D3) at (0.875,0.125);
\coordinate (D4) at (0.875,-0.125); % 
\coordinate (E1) at (0.375,0.375);
\coordinate (E2) at (0.625,0.375);
\coordinate (E3) at (0.525,0.425);
\coordinate (E4) at (0.525,0.325); %
\coordinate (F1) at (0.15,0.015);
\coordinate (F2) at (0.1,-0.015);
\coordinate (F3) at (0.125,0.125);
\coordinate (F4) at (0.125,-0.125); % 
\coordinate (G1) at (0.375,-0.375); 
\coordinate (G2) at (0.625,-0.375);
\coordinate (G3) at (0.475,-0.425);
\coordinate (G4) at (0.575,-0.325);

\begin{scope}[xshift=-2cm, yshift=-.541cm,  scale=.2]
\draw [->] (8.5196,2.38)-- (9.86,2.38);
\draw [color=black] (5.96,4.74)-- (3.86,2.38); 
\draw [color=black] (3.86,2.38)-- (5.34,1.66); 
\draw [color=black] (5.34,1.66)-- (5.96,4.74); 
\draw (5.34,1.66)-- (6.,0.); 
\draw (5.34,1.66)-- (8.08,2.3); 
\draw (3.86,2.38)-- (6.,0.); 
\draw (6.,0.)-- (8.08,2.3); 
\draw (5.96,4.74)-- (8.08,2.3); 
\draw [dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (5.96,4.74)-- (6.38,2.84); 
\draw [dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (6.38,2.84)-- (8.08,2.3); 
\draw [dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (3.86,2.38)-- (6.38,2.84); 
\draw [dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (6.38,2.84)-- (6.,0.);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[dashed] 
\draw (C1) -- (C4) -- (C2) -- (C3) -- (C1); 
\draw (D1) -- (D4) -- (D2) -- (D3) -- (D1); 
\draw (E1) -- (E4) -- (E2) -- (E3) -- (E1); 
\draw (F1) -- (F4) -- (F2) -- (F3) -- (F1); 
\draw (G1) -- (G4) -- (G2) -- (G3) -- (G1); 
\end{scope}

\draw (F3) -- (F2) -- (C1) -- (C3) -- (E4) -- (E1); 
\draw (C1) -- (C4) -- (G3) -- (G1) -- (F4) -- (F2); 
\draw (D1) -- (C2) -- (C3) -- (E4) -- (E2) -- (D3) -- (D1); 
\draw (D1) -- (C2) -- (C4) -- (G3) -- (G2) --(D4) -- (D1); 
\draw (E2) -- (E3) -- (E1) -- (F3) -- (F2) -- (F4) -- (G1) -- (G3) --  (G2) -- (D4) -- (D1) -- (D3) -- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `pdflatex` with pstricks: load package `auto-pst-pdf` after `pstricks`packages, and launch the compiler with the `--enable-write18` switch (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX).

Comment: @Bernard Yes, although it should be noted that this setup is less than ideal. It makes compilation a lot slower because of the extra business that auto-pst-pdf is doing, and I don't believe it always behaves the same as normal pstricks would in terms of output. Also, it clashes with hyperref (although this can be fixed by putting hyperref inside a \ifpdf clause).

Comment: @lukeuser: Usually, Icompile pstricks figures as independent files, and I include the resulting  .pdf  with `\includegraphics`. This makes the compilation slower only for the figures, not for the main file.

Comment: @Bernard Okay, so I've figured out I can add the `[off]` option to auto-pst-pdf and leave a previous `filename-pics.pdf` in the output directory; it simply adds what's in that file to the document on compilation—conceptually similar to what you describe.

Answer (score 2):

At the very least you can make `tikz` do the work of projecting 3-D coordinates onto the page (with very simple perspective): just give coordinates in 3 dimensions. You can also control the projection by specifying the directions of the x,y,z axes. There are also some libraries which define other possibly useful coordinate systems (polar, spherical, etc.).

You'll still have to draw all of the edges on your own, but at least if you know the actual 3D coordinates you won't have to figure out where on the page they should go.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[z={(-.3cm,-.2cm)}, % direction z gets projected to; can also change x,y
                                       % use cm to specify non-transformed coordinates
                    line join=round, line cap=round % makes the corners look nicer
                   ]
  \draw (0,1,0) -- (-1,0,0) -- (0,-1,0) -- (1,0,0) -- (0,1,0) -- (0,0,1) -- (0,-1,0) (1,0,0) -- (0,0,1) -- (-1,0,0);
  \draw[dashed] (0,1,0) -- (0,0,-1) -- (0,-1,0) (1,0,0) -- (0,0,-1) -- (-1,0,0);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: octahedron]